# What is happening internally for auto increment field in data base side and application side?

Tags: spring, hibernate, increment

I have a bean for spring application

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_apply_leave")
public class ApplyLeaveModel{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int dbid;
private String employee_name;


public int getDbid() {
    return dbid;
}
public void setDbid(int dbid) {
    this.dbid = dbid;
}
public String getEmployee_name() {
    return employee_name;
}
public void setEmployee_name(String employee_name) {
    this.employee_name = employee_name;
}
```

}

then In controller before save this object value of dbid is null.
but after save the object using hibernate dbid contains value.
I don't know what's happening.

controller code is:

---

```
     System.out.println(applyLeaveModel.getDbid()); // null
     leave_dao.saveApplyLeaveModel(applyLeaveModel);
     System.out.println(applyLeaveModel.getDbid()); // 5
```

---

```
   public void saveApplyLeaveModel(ApplyLeaveModel applyLeaveModel) {
            Session session = null;
            Transaction trans_obj = null;
            try {
                session = sessionFactory.openSession();
                if (session.isOpen() && session != null) {
                    trans_obj = session.beginTransaction();
                    session.persist(applyLeaveModel);
                } 
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("save ApplyLeaveModel session " + e);
            } finally {
                trans_obj.commit();
                session.close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: what is your database ?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate executes [`PreparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys%28%29) to obtain the generated id after insert.

Also related: [`hibernate.jdbc.use_get_generated_keys`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/apa.html#d5e5164).

Sidenote: Primitive types in Java cannot have `null` value. Probably you mean `0`, or type of the id is `Integer`.